# How to make a text bold in PHP mail()?

Tags: php, function, email, syntax, output

I would like to mail some text as bold in my email content. I have used the following code

```
$to = 'some@gmail.com';
    $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
        $from = $param['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $headers = "From:" . $from;

    $name = $param['name'];

    $subject = "Test";

    $message =  "message.\n\n" 
                ."<b>Name:</b> ".$name . "\n\n"
                ."Adress: \n" 
                .$param['address'] . "\n"
                .$param['zip'] . ", "
                .$param['postal_area'] . "\n\n"
                ."E-post: ".$param['email'] . "\n\n\n"

      mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

I have used `<strong>` also instead of `<b>` tag, but nothing works.
I get mail in the below format :

```
<b>Namn:</b> some name

Adress:
Borås, Sweden
4837, Boras

E-post: somemail@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are overwriting the header variable again. You need to append to it.

```
 $headers .= "From:" . $from; //You forgot to concatenate here...
//     ---^ //Add the .
```

Answer (score 4):

Try setting the font weight property in a span:

```
$message = "E-post: <span style='font-weight:strong;'>".$param['email']."</span>";
```

But also see other reply, you are overwriting the header so it is not reading the message as HTML.